# Maintaining a database-like structure in RAM

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine, game-development, deep-copy

I am creating a game that simulates a galaxy of many star systems, and within those star systems are planets, ships, colonies, etc..

The player controls a single ship and will be exploring and interacting with the galaxy. Each ship, including the player's, has a computer system on board with a database. This database stores that ship's current understanding of the galaxy based on what the ship has scanned, which may or may not line up with what is true in the actual simulation, especially if the data is quite out of date.

Basically, the galaxy simulation is the source of truth, and each ship has its own database that stores its own version of the truth which affects what that ship is aware of and how it behaves. For example, the player ship arrives in a system and its scan only detects some of the ships in that system. The details (positions, velocity, etc.) of those ships would then be added to the player ship's database and updated as long as the player ship maintains a scan on those ships. Once the other ships go out of range, the player ship's database still has saved the details of those ships that it found, which can be valuable information, but that information is no longer up to date.

All that to say that I am having trouble deciding on the best way to make deep clones of the simulation data to be stored on the ship's database. My requirements are:

1. It has to be deep clones of simulation data that is stored on the ship.
2. A ship can get partial deep clones of data from another ship. Sometimes the scanning ship only gets partial information, i.e. it might learn of the enemy ship's position and velocity and some of its weapons, but fails to scan some other weapons on the enemy ship.
3. The ship's database needs to store some sort of Identifier so that if, for example, it loses contact with another ship and then regains contact, it knows that it already has an entry in the database for that ship and updates that instead of generating a new entry.
4. Each ship's database probably has to stay stored in RAM most of the time due to how frequently a lot of the data will be updated.

Let's say this is my ship class which my player ship is scanning:

```
public class Ship
{        
    public Guid Id;
    public List<Engine> Engines;
    public List<Weapon> Weapons;
    public double VelocityX;
    public double VelocityY;
    public double PositionX;
    public double PositionY;
}
```

I know it's easy enough to make a deep clone of this object and just throw it into a dictionary with the key being the Id. But what if I only want to deep clone a few of the variables, and its different each time? Another tricky thing is if our player ship only scans a few of the other ship's weapons. The weapon might have an Id property as well, but I can't just reuse this Ship object because the weapons are stored in a list, not a dictionary, and so if this ship goes out of sight and then back into sight I have no way to check an Id and make sure that it matches the weapon we already know about.

My initial thought is that I need a corresponding new class for each object, like ShipInfo, which basically stores the same properties, but any lists/hashsets are stored as dictionaries:

```
public class ShipInfo
{        
    public Guid Id;
    public Dictionary<Guid, EngineInfo> Engines;
    public Dictionary<Guid, WeaponInfo> Weapons;
    public double VelocityX;
    public double VelocityY;
    public double PositionX;
    public double PositionY;
}
```

And then I'll need some sort of helper functions in order to manually clone the specific objects from the Ship class that are scanned. It just feels like a lot of duplication to have both a Ship class and a ShipInfo class.

I feel like there must be a better way to do this that I'm not thinking of and that will require less (what feels like) duplication work than my current approach. Maybe I'm looking at this in the completely wrong way.

Anyway, I hope this makes sense, and I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: `But what if I only want to deep clone a few of the variables` which ones? Except the lists and dictionaries they are all value type fields anyway ...

Comment: And yeah then I guess you would simply store a `Dictionary<Guid, ShipInfo>` or even simply `HashSet<ShipInfo>` (using the `Guid` as hash) and then add new entries if you have new items or update existing ones ...

Comment: `feels like a lot of duplication to have both a Ship class and a ShipInfo class.` .. kinda yes .. it would make sense though in my eyes if the `Ship` class is the one that actually has a behavior like moving etc .. and then it has no fields itself but rather simply actually has a `ShipInfo` field .. this also gives you your entry point for the scanning -> you simply checkout the values from that ShipInfo of that Ship

Comment: @derHugo `which ones? Except the lists and dictionaries they are all value type fields anyway` Every scan can be different, so it can be any possible combination of the fields. I also just gave a very simplified version of the Ship class, but you can imagine it has tens of variables with plenty of reference types.

Comment: @derHugo my reason for not wanting to make the ShipInfo class attached to the Ship class is that I want to take advantage of the small performance increases of iterating through non-dictionary ienumerables. These performance gains do matter since due to the large number of entities I am simulating per frame. Therefore what I am proposing is that the ShipInfo class basically just contains the duplicate fields of the Ship class, but replacing all the Lists with Dictionaries. But yeah, it feels a bit silly as each modification to the ship class requires a modification to the ShipInfo class, etc..

Comment: That's why I mean the Ship could have a ShipInfo then you only have to change the values once. whether you then scan a ship and access it's fields or the ShipInfo and it's fields makes barely a difference. And then as said you definitely want `Dictionary` in order to be able to update specific items by Guid. For the copying you can simply iterate the `Dictionary` as well which implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Tk, Tv>>` and then personally I would implement a method like `DeepCopy` in to your info classes which returns a new instance with copied values

Comment: @derHugo my only concern with that is that I know iterating the `IEnumberable<KeyValuePair<Tk, Tv>>` is slower than other IEnumerables. It's not a huge amount, but I worry that it will make a difference on my game's performance over thousands of Dictionaries per frame